# How to draw rectangles over ImageView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, imageview, tensorflow-lite

I have created an application to detect objects. I have already got a list of coordinates of bounding boxes and I would like to draw these bounding boxes in pictures (ImageViews).

[Here is what I have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkLj2.jpg)

[And here is what I would like to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1vhS.jpg)

Do you have any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can take a look at this https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview

github also shows the code, use bitmap
https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/e5fcd871a9ef4066f8db7d86941a710271f8ed89/lite/examples/object_detection/android/app/src/main/java/org/tensorflow/lite/examples/detection/DetectorActivity.java#L151